# Transform one table into another with sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table1 which I want to transform into table 2. The table consists of a series of properties and dates. Some records make have Review Dates and others may not. I want to return a list of properties and all corresponding review dates, and there should always be a record with a null showing in the Review Date. Finally, I want to return the previous review date in the last column, which is the most recent review date on the other records for the property. Please advise how to transform in an efficient manner. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`Property` varchar(1), `ReviewDate` varchar(9), `Due` datetime)
 ;

INSERT INTO Table1
(`Property`, `ReviewDate`, `Due`)
 VALUES
('A', '1/31/2017', '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', NULL, '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00')
;




CREATE TABLE Table2
(`Property` varchar(1), `ReviewDate` varchar(9), `Due` datetime, `PreviousReviewDate` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
(`Property`, `ReviewDate`, `Due`, `PreviousReviewDate`)
VALUES
('A', NULL, NULL, '1/31/2017'),
('A', '1/31/2017', '2017-03-30 19:00:00', '1/15/2016'),
('A', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00', '1/10/2015'),
('A', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00', NULL),
('B', NULL, '2017-03-30 19:00:00', '1/15/2016'),
('B', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00', '1/10/2015'),
('B', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00', NULL)
;
```

Comment: Always mention the version of db or software your are using. This will help you to get better answer. what version of SQL Server are you using. also tag your question with sql-server

Comment: What is the first row in Table2 ? ('A', NULL, NULL, '1/31/2017'), why do you have this row?

Comment: I want there to always be a record with no review date. Think of it as a receivable.

Comment: Hi, if the answer are ok, can you upvote (one or many answer) and mark as resolve your preferred answer. Thanks for zambonee and me. Please considere this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e82a6/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(Property varchar(1), ReviewDate date, Due datetime);

INSERT INTO Table1
(Property, ReviewDate, Due)
VALUES
('A', '1/31/2017', '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', NULL, '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00');

CREATE TABLE Table2
(Property varchar(1), ReviewDate date, Due datetime, PreviousReviewDate date);

INSERT INTO Table2 (Property, ReviewDate, Due, PreviousReviewDate)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES COALESCE(Curr.Property, Prev.Property), Curr.ReviewDate, Curr.Due, Prev.ReviewDate AS PreviousReviewDate 
FROM Table1 AS Curr
FULL JOIN Table1 AS Prev
ON Curr.Property = Prev.Property
AND Prev.ReviewDate < COALESCE(Curr.ReviewDate, GETDATE())
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Curr.Property, Curr.ReviewDate, Curr.Due ORDER BY Prev.ReviewDate DESC)
```

Join the table with itself where Property = Property and Date < Date to get all previous dates for each date. Then, select the top rows, ordering by the previous date so that the top result is the latest date. You also have to handle nulls for the ReviewDate (I assumed a missing date can be handled as the current date).

Also, I suggest using the `date` type instead of `varchar` for those date fields.

Answer (score 0):

auto join + inequality join + group by.

Join each row with same `Property` and choose the `Max(ReviewDate)` (before the current) to determine the previous

This solution is compliant with standard SQL (Postgres, SqlServer, ...)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(Property varchar(1), ReviewDate date, Due datetime)
 ;

INSERT INTO Table1
(Property, ReviewDate, Due)
 VALUES
('A', '1/31/2017', '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('A', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', NULL, '2017-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/15/2016', '2016-03-30 19:00:00'),
('B', '1/10/2015', '2015-03-30 19:00:00')
;


Create Table2 as
Select
    coalesce(A.Property,B.Property) as Property,        
    A.ReviewDate,
    A.Due, 
    Max(B.ReviewDate) as PreviousReviewDate
From
   Table1 A
   full join Table1 B On
        A.Property   = B.Property and
        A.ReviewDate > B.ReviewDate 
group by
   A.Property,A.ReviewDate,A.Due,B.Property
having
   not(A.ReviewDate is null and  Max(B.ReviewDate) is null)
```

Comment: From my mobile device... but the idea is here. I try to format the code and I update it 

Comment: I have reformat and rewrite my code, we have about the same idea with @zambonee